# Cypress and auth app with sections. Can you call a shared test, ie login?

Tags: cypress

I'm new to cypress. Lets say I have the following structure. Each should be run in a vacuum, BUT they all require a login. I understad I could create a  "command" that for login. but lets say I have a test, ala login.spec.js

And all it does is log in a user and redirects. Great.

BUT, after that, various devs will want to run their own tests given their particular domains. But they will all need to login, so rather than always creating the same test.. is there a way to "share" a test, then continue on with the tests that they are interested in?

For example: ** FOLDER NAME **

```
**Integration**
  login.spec.js
  **CreateProduct**
     index.spec.js
  **PurchaseProduct** // <-- I want to run this, BUT with login.spec.js too as a before hook.
     index.spec.js
  etc...
```

Now, I want to just run the tests in the PurchaseProduct folder, BUT they need to first be "logged in"... so, I want to call login.spec.js... HOW can that be used across all usages of those who want to borrow it?

Comment: You can `import '../login.spec'` at the top of other specs to run login tests prior to others in the spec, although I do not see it as a better option than a login command.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `Cypress` supports the ability to create and reuse actions and state in your UI, such as registering and logging in before a test.

*However*, `Cypress`, through `cy.request()` allows you to control the state of the browser more powerfully than a user would, making your tests **simpler**, **faster**, **more reliable**

Check out this example below where `cy.request` is used to create/read state on your server.

In `commands/index.js`:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (user) => {
    cy.request('POST', `${apiUrl}/users/login`, user)
})

Cypress.Commands.add("register", (user) => {
    cy.request('POST', `${apiUrl}/users/register`, user)
})

Cypress.Commands.add('getUser', (username) => {
    return cy.request('GET', `${apiUrl}/users/${username}`)
})
```

in `register.spec.js`:

```js
it ('can register', () => {
    const user = {
      name: 'jake',
      email: 'jake@jake.com',
      password: '12345'
    }

    cy.visit('/register')
    cy.get('input[name="name"]').type(user.name)
    cy.get('input[name="email"]').type(user.email)
    cy.get('input[name="password"]').type(user.password)
    cy.get('input[name="password-confirm"]').type(user.password)
    cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click()

    // ensure register page sends you /home after register
    cy.url().should('contain', '/home')

    // expect user from server to match user from test
    cy.getUser(user.name)
    .then((dbUser) => expect(dbUser).to.deep.eql(user))
})
```

in `login.spec.js`:

```js
it('can log in', () => {
    const user = {
        name: 'jane',
        email: 'jane@jane.com',
        password: '12345'
    }

    // register w/out UI
    cy.register(user)

    cy.visit('/login')
    cy.get('input[name="name"]').type(user.name)
    cy.get('input[name="password"]').type(user.password)
    cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click()

    // ensure the login page sends you home after login
    cy.url().should('contain', '/home')
})
```

in `userSettings.spec.js`:

```js
it('can change email', () => {
    const user = {
        name: 'jane',
        email: 'jane@jane.com',
        password: '12345'
    }

    // register and login w/o UI
    cy.register(user)
    cy.login(user)

    cy.visit('/settings')
    cy.get('input[name="email"]').type('UpdatedEmail@jane.com')
    cy.get('input[type="submit"]').click()

    cy.getUser(user.name)
    .then((dbUser) => expect(dbUser.email).to.eql('UpdatedEmail@jane.com'))
})
```

Comment: This is great. A problem I am running into is my whole app is graphql. There are no exposed API'S that I would hope to just stub. Do you have any examples of graphql mutations stubs?

Comment: @jamesemanon if you ask that as a separate question I could take a stab at it!

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51012988/cypress-w-graphql-having-issues-getting-auth-with-testing-via-ui-better-way-t

Comment: @jamesemanon thanks, could you accept my answer if it answers your question?

Answer (score 1):

You understand you could create a command for login. Any reason for not doing so then ?

If you haven't already, I recommend watching this presentation from Cypress's founder Brian Mann, referenced on [one of the official doc pages](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/testing-your-app.html#). Please find below two sections that seem to relate to your question.

[3 strategies to test the login page (8:40)](https://youtu.be/5XQOK0v_YRE?t=854)

- stub requests, don't actually authenticate
- OR static user in the DB
- OR dynamic user created by tests

[Centralize login (15:35)](https://youtu.be/5XQOK0v_YRE?t=935)

> (9 minutes later) We don't **have to**, nor should you **ever**, use the UI to
>   build up state

Comment: The principles are good, but the solution Brian gives using localstorage means the test knows too much about the internal workings of the app (hence fragile if internals change). A far better approach is if Cypress could somehow snapshot state after the login test and recall that state at the beginning of subsequent tests. I think this may be what James is looking for.